# Do you know a webhook which should work with a proxy?

Tags: python-3.x, webhooks, dialogflow-es, http-proxy, ngrok

I'm looking for a webhook which is able to work with a proxy, because in my company I have to set up the proxy every time I use a software. I want a webhook for dialogflow, and the language I'm using is Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

Webhook is basically a web service. depending on the way you write the webhook you have to configure it for the proxy(without taking a look at your current implementation it is hard to tell what is wrong.). there is nothing you can do about that from the dialogflow. basically dialog flow will send your web service a post request and for that you have to send a response. that is how dialogflow [webhook](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) works. also your webhook will only work if it is hosted somewhere or you a have publicly accessible IP address. otherwise how could it work.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, indeed I could set the proxy from ngrok, I found it finally, the solution is in the ./ngrok  put the line http_proxy: "http://user:password@proxy.company:3128"